# Asynchronous amazon glacier download

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I want to asynchronously download multiple glacier files using thread pool. My current approach uses High Level API for Glacier download, but every thread waits at download method until the download job is complete. Below is the code where all the treads are waiting

```
            ArchiveTransferManager manager = new     ArchiveTransferManager(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            DownloadOptions options = new DownloadOptions();
            manager.Download(vaultName, archiveId, downloadFilePath, options);
```

Can somebody please suggest me how to download archive asynchronously, so that my thread should come back after getting the job id and some event should get raised on download completion.

Regards,
Haseena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Amazon doesn't offer an asynchronous API, you'll need to implement one yourself. You already have a thread for each download, just have your download thread notify your main thread when the download is done.

TPL can help you do that automatically - create a Task that downloads a file, and `await` on it.

Comment: Each archive in glacier is a small chunk for me of size 512 KB, we have some internal logic for which we have maintain the size small.so if i want to download a file of size 1 GB , i will have 2048 threading running in memory.

Comment: You won't get 2048 running threads, the thread pool is not that large.

Comment: I think i will be able to achieve this using low level API for glacier download. Low Level .net API gives job id and queue URL once the request is added for download, i can use this job id(s) and url(s) in a separate thread for pooling.