# Amazon Glacier Asynchronous Download

Tags: asp.net, amazon-glacier

How to asynchronously download multiple amazon glacier files in asp.net web application. I am using .Net 3.5.

Comment: SO is not a "How To" site. Please read the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/V3/DeveloperGuide/glacier-apis-intro.html), try it yourself, and if you encounter problems with your code, come back here.

Comment: I have tried the following code and it is not asynchronous

                   var options = new DownloadOptions();
                    options.StreamTransferProgress += OnProgress;
                    manager.Download(ReadConfig.AWSVaultName, archiveId, downloadPath, options);

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451833/asynchronous-amazon-glacier-download
What is the asp.net context?

Comment: @Alexander I need sample code.